# C++ "Interface" class implement base class function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I have a base class which I'm trying to use like an interface, then I have a derived class that I want to implement the two functions in B, but I'm getting compile errors.

B.hh

```
template <class A>
class B {

    public: 
        virtual void setStatus(A status);
        virtual void updateState();

};
```

C.hh:

```
class C: public B<D*>
```

C.cpp

```
void C::updateState() { ... }
void C::setStatus(D* state) { ...}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
error: no ‘void C::updateState()’ member function declared in class ‘C’
error: no ‘void C::setStatus(D*)’ member function declared in class ‘C’
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] including all files and their complete contents (but reduced to the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue by copy-pasting the code to files and compiling).

Comment: What part of the error messages isn't clear to you? There _is_ no such member function declared in class `C`, after all. Note that you still need to redeclare it even if you're overriding it from `B`.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The question is quite clear.

Comment: The template class `B` has two member functions: `setStatus` and `updateState`. You know that because that's what the class definition says. The class `C` has no member functions of its own. You know that because that's what the class definition says. It **inherits** the two member functions from `B`, so you can call the `B` versions on an object of type `C`,  but `C` doesn't have its own versions of them. To add them, add declarations to the definition of `C` just like the ones in `B`.